# Changing Docker engine version on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application I want to deploy as a Docker container using Amazons Beanstalk platform. However the application is only certified against v17 of Docker, but Beanstalk uses v18 of Docker.

Is there a way of configuring Beanstalk to use a specific version of Docker? I cannot find any options to do this when I create my application within the AWS console (I have signed up for a free account so maybe such an option is for paid versions).

Comment: You're not going to be able to change that on Beanstalk.  AWS manages this service for you and they're only going to support what they have.  You could run on an EC2 where you can control everything but then you've got much more to configure to match what Beanstalk gives you.  Having said that, have you tried it on 18?  I've not had issues changing versions before.

Comment: @stdunbar I suspected that would be the answer. I have not tried it on Docker 18 yet, but the issue is even if it does work, if there are any bugs that get raised against it in the future, then because it is not certified against v18, we may not get support for it, even if the Docker version in reality is not the issue.